# CSS or JQuery Hover effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>hello</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("img").mouseenter(function(){
                $("#hello").css("width", "400px");
            });
            $("img").mouseleave(function(){
                $("#hello").css("width", "50px"));
            });
        });
        
    </script> 
    
    
    
</head>

<body>
    
    
    
    <img id="hello" src="img/hello.png">
    
    

</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Hi Everyone,

I have this image where I want to add some hover effects.

Initially I want just the chart logo to be shown, then when someone hovers over it it will expand to display the whole image and goes back to chart logo only when the pointer leaves.

I have tried using jquery moueeneter mouseleave effect but i cant get the effect i want. This there any simple or best way to achieve this ? Many Thanks :)

Comment: Show your code, what you have tried so far. so we can help.

Comment: you could try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/hgpgbu1c/ have two images and interchange them on hover

Comment: I have added the code I am working on atm :)

Comment: This won't work because you are stretching the entire image. Wrap it in a container with `overflow:hidden` and readjust it's size, then it will work.

Comment: check this other sample https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/hgpgbu1c/1/... i set the width from 2 different classes and toggleClass on mouseover...

Comment: ahh yes that could work thanks i am also trying shrinking the image to reveal the whole lot :)

Comment: try it...hope it works for your requirements :)

Comment: @Hkhan updated the fiddle for reference https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/hgpgbu1c/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try a pure css solution such as this

```css
#hello{width:200px;} /*this is just limiting the width for preview reasons*/


#hello{-webkit-transition: all 1s ease; 
 transition: all 1s ease; /*this animates the transition*/
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 55% 0, 55% 100%, 0% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 55% 0, 55% 100%, 0% 100%);
  
}
#hello:hover{
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<img id="hello" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/d42l2.png">
```

Comment: this is the effect i was trying to achieve well similar  thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Its actually quite simple.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").on({
 "mouseover" : function() {
    $('#imageid').css({'width' : '700px' , 'height' : '700px'});
  },
  "mouseout" : function() {
    $('#imageid').css({'width' : '70px' , 'height' : '70px'});
  }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <img id="imageid"  src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif" style="width:70px;height:70px">
</body>
</html>
```

You can use the same logic for hover as well. Here is the plunker just in case:https://plnkr.co/edit/kFVhlsK8uwFwZkiA5o56?p=preview

And, here the plunker using jquery hover: https://plnkr.co/edit/z0EZG33GeKe7icAFmxK2?p=preview

Comment: should have marked it correct if it was correct and to your need :) Afterall, the first answer to your question was what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is an example with some css transition

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").on({"mouseover" : function() {
    $('img').css({'width' : '200px' , 'height' : '200px'});
  },
    "mouseout" : function() {
    $('img').css({'width' : '100px' , 'height' : '100px'});
  }
  });
});
```

```css
img {
 transition: width 1s, height 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image"  src="http://placehold.it/350x150" style="width:100px;height:100px">
```